# Image Not working in Html/jsp

Tags: html, jsp

I am having a problem with my image not coming up when it should. My code is `<img src="/WebContent/manuLogo.jpg" alt="chelsea Logo" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" />`. I'm using eclipse with HTML JSP and CSS. I know the tag is correct but I don't know why its not showing the image.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Java

Comment: Answer is probably "because src is the wrong url"

Comment: It is in the webcontent folder though thats the thing

Comment: Have been able to load _any_ other images?

Comment: No the same thing happens.

Comment: Have you tried using just "/manuLogo.jpg" without `WebContent`?

Comment: Have you tried following a tutorial, or deploying a pre-built sample application? Is this the first jsp-based application you've ever written?

Comment: It is not my first...I have used the same line for images in other projects dealing with jsp that is why I am confused.

Comment: Good then. So if you have a project that works and a project that doesn't, then something _must_ be different between the two, yes? You say you've used "the same line for images", but that just means you're looking in the wrong place for the difference.

Comment: I'll give it a shot thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the `WebContent` folder is in the same directory as the html.file with the above code, omit the leading slash of the image path:

```
<img src="WebContent/manuLogo.jpg" alt="chelsea Logo" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" />
```